# List with in a List Datatable Extension with the property Info

Tags: c#, generics

I am converting from Datatable to List by using Datatable Extensions. 
Here when i am trying to add a row to a normal List property its working fine. 
But when i use a list with in a list i am facing problem. i am not able to set the value in property.

```
 private static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row, IList<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
    {
        T item = new T();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {

            if (property.Name.Equals("ProductSpec"))
            {
                Type t = property.GetType();
                //  i am getting error when i am trying to do this

                property.SetValue(item, ProductSpecIteration(property, row), null);
            }

            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(property.Name))
            {                   
                property.SetValue(item, row[property.Name] == DBNull.Value?"":row[property.Name], null);
            }

        }
        return item;
    }


 private static ProductSpec ProductSpecIteration(PropertyInfo property, DataRow row)
    {            
        ProductSpec lstProductSpec = new ProductSpec();
        lstProductSpec.product_specs_id = Convert.ToInt64(row["product_specs_id"]);            
        return lstProductSpec;
    }
```

I am not able to generically do this. But even i am not able to add this in this extensions? Could any one help me out from this situations

Comment: can you post some details on the error?

Comment: the error is "Object must implement IConvertible"

Comment: and you get it when you do `Convert.ToInt64(row["product_specs_id"]);`?

Comment: @Wolf, That should not be the case, because `row["column"]` should return `object` which is convertible to `long`. @Bhuvan, did you try debugging the code, where is the exception occuring?

Comment: OK then what is the exact line where you get the error? It is when you're doing `property.SetValue(...)` for properties other than the id? Can you debug and see for which property you get it and what is the value?

Comment: first thing is i am not able to set the List which is ina property , so i manually hardcoded and assigned the values in a  list  which is a metyhod ProductSpecIteration. Now when i try to set the actual List to a property i am getting error exactly at this line "  property.SetValue(item, ProductSpecIteration(property, row), null);
            }" . In my debug after the completion of ProductSpecIteration i am facing this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U r trying to convert the object returned from DataRow.Item[string] property which cannot be set directly.

```
string value = row[property.Name] == DBNull.Value?"":row[property.Name].ToString();
property.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType), null);
```

for the ProductSpec u can use,

```
  ProductSpec spec = ProductSpecIteration(property, row);
  property.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(spec , property.PropertyType), null);
```

However, it will work fine without changing the type as the type is same as property type

Hope this helps.
You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977.aspx) 
You can also read more about **IConvertible** Interface [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx)

**IConvertible** interface helps in returning a required value, since object does not implement IConvertible and hence cannot get the value in required format of the property type.

Comment: In Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType).. If the value is a List, will this works?

Comment: It will help in assigning the whole list. To add individual elements u need to invoke the "Add" method on the object u got from the property

Comment: But still i am getting an error as object must implement iConvertible... do i need to implement his for all the methods

Comment: Also, Did u use ToString() on the item retrieved from the data row? like this lstProductSpec.product_specs_id = Convert.ToInt64(row["product_specs_id"].ToString());

Comment: i should not use this because i had defined my product_specs_id  as int in my productspec model

Comment: u r using the wrong type, it should be property.PropertyType
property.GetType() will give u typeof(PropertyInfo)

Comment: Hi.. As i am using List with in a list i am getting my type as "System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo"

Comment: use property.PropertyType which gives u the type of property

Comment: PropertyType is retreving my genericList  ProductSpec..but when i try i am receiving the same error

Comment: invoke the "Add" method on the list, that is how u add an object to the list

Comment: But my list is in a property variable of propertyinfo type.. how do i add my lstproductspec to my propertyinfo type variable